How to define TraceLevel for TraceError, TraceWarning, TraceInformation?
I cannot find out, how to set the TraceLevel for Trace.TraceInformation, so that Trace.TraceInformation writes only when the TraceLevel is set from Information level and above.
I created a WEB API project with the "ASP.NET WebApplication(.NET Framework)" template and .NET 4.7.2. I call Trace.TraceInformation as follows in the ValuesController:
Imports System.Web.Http

Public Class ValuesController
    Inherits ApiController

    ' GET api/values
    Public Function GetValues() As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Trace.TraceInformation("GetValues")
        Return New String() {"value1", "value2"}
    End Function
End Class

The trace is written to a file, because in Global.asax.vb I have the following code:
    Sub Application_Start()
        ...
        Dim traceListener = Trace.Listeners(0)
        CType(traceListener, DefaultTraceListener).LogFileName = "C:\Temp\WebApplication2\Log1.log"
    End Sub
End Class


How can I specify in Web.config the TraceLevel? I want for example in the Web.config to set the TraceLevel to Error, so that Trace.TraceInformation does not write to the file. When I set the TraceLevel to Information, I want Trace.TraceInformation to write to the file.

I created the project with the "ASP.NET WebApplication(.NET Framework)" template, which does not create any diagnostics configuration in the Web.config, therefore the DefaultTraceListener is used.
I tried to add the following in Web.config, but Trace.TraceInformation continues to write to the file:
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="DefaultSource" switchName="DefaultSwitch"/>
    </sources>
    <switches>
      <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Error"/>
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>


How is the TraceSwitch called for the DefaultTraceListener?

